# SHELL - Deleting files under home directory and its sub-directories in a single command line

Tags: shell, recursion, command-line, terminal, rm

I want to find all the files that contain the string "red" under my home directory and all its sub-directories in one command line. I am using the Terminal on Mac. This is what I have so far:

```
$ cd && rm -ri *red*
```

I was hoping that my -r argument would recursively go through all the directories starting from the home directory, but it's not quite working. Is there a simpler way to delete certain files under a directory and its sub-directories? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this. For example:

```
find ~ -name "*red*" -type f | xargs rm
```

The `find` part will look recurcively for all files (`-type f`) containing the string red (`-name "*red*"`) at your home directory (`~`) and output the list of the files. Then we pipe the list to the `xargs` command that will call `rm` for each file.